# Angular 2/4 - Is it possible to initialize a provider only after a promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

In my provider's constructor I have something like:

```
constructor(
    public http: Http
  ) {
    this.http.get("api.php").toPromise().then(res=>this.res = res.json());
  }
```

However, I only want this provider to be accessible only after `this.http.get("api.php").toPromise()` is resolved. Everything else should be the same as a normal provider, such as the way it is injected. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Good question, but why do you want that .

Comment: Need to make sure `this.res` is available.

Comment: and what to do when the provider is requested in the constructor and the class is being initialized?

Comment: Perhaps any class that depends on this provider should wait until the promise is resolved? I don't know. What's the angular way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did with AngularJS :

- initialize you attribute with `var = $q.defer()`
- when you meet the requested value, use `var.resolve(value)`
- And until you get the value, you can postpone treatments using `var.promise.then(function (data) { ... })`

Whole code of a service :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('myService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    s.myVar = $q.defer();

    s.loadMyVar = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "somewhere"
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            s.myVar.resolve(response.data);                   
        });

    };

    s.getMyVar = function () {
        return s.myVar.promise.then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    };

    return s;

}]);
```